# Drupal Commerce Check out

Tags: commerce

I am using Drupal 7 commerce; I would like to set up the check out process to skip the payment portion and just send an email to the admin and the customer. How do I do that?

Thank you for you help.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Let me advise you to read [How do I ask a good question?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) article in Help Center's [Asking](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/asking) section.

Answer (score 1):

Just disable the Payment module and edit the default checkout completion rule that emails the customer to include an action that emails the administrator.